# What is the Ohm measure value of this resistor?

Tags: resistors, resistance

Resistor Ohms Value?
In diode mode test, it will show continuity or sound. is fused or blown. It is in the negative line of Electrolytic 400volts 22uf capacitor, such capacitor in direct after the diode bridge rectifier. As I said the resistor is in the negative line direct current of 400volts line, the resistor is between the capacitor and the Source of the Mosfet SVF4N65(4A,650V N-CHANNEL)
I really cant apply the standard code color to figure what Ohms it is. It is part of a commuted power supply of a Chinese amplifier speaker. There is no diagram on earth to get information of. Just one poor picture from the manufacturer that I attach.
May you help guys to calculate of figure it out the value of this overseas resistor?
Black - Yellow - Violet - Grey - Brown

[image]

Comment: probably 047 * 0.01 = 0.47 Ohms. I assume the second ring is yellow but looks a bit greenish because of the blue background.

Comment: Did you measure it with normal ohms mode on the DMM? That might be silver, not gray, silver is a 0.01 multiplier, this might be a very low value resistor.

Comment: in 200 Ohmmeter, the lowest scale in my DMM, measure is 0.06 fluctuating 0.07 it never get stability reading.

Comment: Do you really need to know the value, or do you just want to know if it is still good? Based on the appearance and your test, it is almost certainly good.

Comment: Meter leads are typically a few tenths of an ohm, so I don't understand your ohmmeter reading. Are you sure you have the decimal point correct?

Comment: Thank you so much in advance. You're right. It is 00.6 or 00.7 in 200 scale Ohmmeter. I need to know the value, to order it. Since 3 diodes are blown, I though it will be a good idea to change components for new ones. never Seen a black band in the first place before.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a 0.47\$\Omega\$ +/-1% resistor, maybe 1W or 2W rating.

If it measures continuity it's probably fine.

If it measures much less than that, it could be a leading zero (non-standard marking) for 0.047 ohms. Again, it’s probably okay if it measures close to that. Resistors do not tend to fail with lower resistance, at least not without fireworks.